# Getting undefined from javascript module property

Tags: javascript

I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious.  I'm returning a variable from my javascript module, but it keeps coming back undefined.

Here's the module:

```
var MyNs = MyNs || {}; 
MyNs.Global = function () {
   var privateTestVar;
   var init = function () {
       if (privateTestVar == null ) {
           privateTestVar = "this is a test" ;
           console.log( 'Init: ' + privateTestVar);
       }
   };

   var Public = {
       init: init,
       TestVar: privateTestVar
   }

   return Public;
} ();
```

Here's the call:

```
MyNs.Global.init();console.log( 'Called: ' +MyNs.Global.TestVar);
```

The console.log in the init function works fine and returns the value, but the other console log returns undefined.  I'm totally missing it.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**  I've change the code a bit, to this:

```
    var privateTestVar = function () { return 'Test!'; }

var Public = {
    TestVar: privateTestVar
}
```

And variations of that, but it returns this exact text to the console:  "function () { return 'Test!'; }"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time that `Public` is assigned here:

```
var Public = {
    init: init,
    TestVar: privateTestVar
}
```

`privateTestVar` is still undefined (because `init()` hasn't been run yet) so the `TestVar` property is initialized to the value of `privateTestVar` which is `undefined`.

The `TestVar` property gets assigned the value of `privateTestVar`.  If it's initially undefined (which it is in this case), it will stay that way until you assign something different to the `TestVar` property.  I won't automatically inherit future values of `privateTestVar` which is perhaps what you were expecting.  Javascript does not have a way of specifying that one variable will always contain whatever is assigned to another variable.  `privateTestVar` and the TestVar` property each have their own value.  Assigning something to one variable does not affect the other.

Comment: Actually, I call the "init" function first, which should assign a value to privateTestVar, making it suitable for returning.

Comment: @JoshC - where is `init()` called?  It's not called in your example before `TestVar` is assigned the value of `privateTestVar` so that's why `TestVar` contains `undefined`.  `init()` would have to be called BEFORE the `TestVar` property was created and initialized.

Comment: It's called like so: MyNs.Global.init();console.log('Called: ' +MyNs.Global.TestVar);

Comment: @JoshC - please read what I've written several times.  You're calling it too late.  The value of `TestVar` is already set in the declaration of `Public` when you then call `init()`.  So you calling `init()` does not affect the value of the `TestVar` property in any way.

Comment: Okay...I see what you mean...sorry...I read right past it a few times.  I wan't quite groking that by returning public, that means it's called first.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest making a private variable really a private one, using getters instead. This will work correctly:

```
var Public = {
    init: init,
    getVar: function() { return privateTestVar; }
}

MyNs.Global.init();console.log( 'Called: ' +MyNs.Global.getVar());
```

Comment: Okay....this is really odd...now it returns the actual text in the function. The console reads like this: "Called: function () { return privateTestVar; }"

Comment: It means you're trying to log the function itself, not its result. Don't forget the parenthesis (`Global.getVar()`).

Answer (score 0):

Issue is as stated by @jfriend00. Change the code to

```
var init = function () {
    if (privateTestVar == null ) {
        privateTestVar = "this is a test" ;
        Public.TestVar = privateTestVar;
        console.log( 'Init: ' + privateTestVar);
    }
};
```

I didn't test this out but theoretically it should work.

Comment: Use raina77ow's suggestion. It's better.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the structure you are looking for:

```
function PrivateFunc(private, public){
  this.privateVar = private;
  this.publicVar = public;
}
function PublicFun(public){
  this.publicVar = public;
  if(this.publicVar == null)this.publicVar = 'This is a public variable.';
  this.PrivateFun = function(private){
    return new PrivateFunc(private, this.publicVar);
  }
}

var pf = new PublicFun('public variable');
var pv = pf.PrivateFun('private variable');
console.log('pf.publicVar = '+pf.publicVar);
console.log('pf.privateVar = '+pf.privateVar);
console.log('pv.publicVar = '+pv.publicVar);
console.log('pv.privateVar = '+pv.privateVar);
```

Notice that `PrivateFunc` is not `PrivateFun`. The real factor comes down to the key word `this`. `this` refers to the current Object as when you type `this`. `var` is only accessible inside your method. You should think of a **JavaScript** Object as an Associative Array. If that doesn't suit your needs try:

```
var jsObject = {
  publicVar: null,
  PrivateFun: function(private){
    var privateVar = private; //cannot access with dot
    return this;
  },
  PublicFun: function(public){
    this.publicVar = public;
    if(this.publicVar == null)this.publicVar = 'This is a public variable';
    return this;
  }
}

var pf = jsObject.PublicFun();
var pv = jsObject.PrivateFun('private variable');
console.log('pf.publicVar = '+pf.publicVar);
console.log('pf.privateVar = '+pf.privateVar);
console.log('pv.publicVar = '+pv.publicVar);
console.log('pv.privateVar = '+pv.privateVar+' //cannot access with dot');
```

Note that Object Literals are not Constructors, so you cannot make `new` instances. Also, in the Object Literal case, `var privateVar` is virtually useless, unless you don't want the `privateVar` returned. `this` must be returned in order to access jsObject, which holds the reference to `publicVar`.